# Вывод данных. Библиотека Datetime на Python

Tags: python

```
import re
from datetime import datetime , date, time
def date_time(time: str) -> str:
    s = datetime.strptime(time, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")
    return s.strftime("%d %B %Y year %H hours %M minutes")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Example:")
    print(date_time('01.01.2000 00:00'))
#1 January 2000 year 0 hours 0 minutes - так должно отображаться
```

Мой код выводит следующее: "01 January 2000 year 00 hours 00 minutes".
Как изменить тип вывода дней с '01' на '1' (без нуля)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

самое просто решение
Под виндой

```
return s.strftime("%#d %B %Y year %H hours %M minutes")
```

под линукс

```
return s.strftime("%-d %B %Y year %H hours %M minutes")
```

еще вариант

```
return s.strftime("%e %B %Y year %H hours %M minutes")
```

Comment: Выводит 01 January, Нужно 1 January. Без нуля. А в 3 варианте пишет как надо, только оставляет перед значением пробел. Знаю что можно про добавить в конце [1:], но иначе решить нельзя?

Comment: Интересует еще вот что. Аналогия с Hours и minutes, как вывести просто по одному нулю?

Comment: @Alealan у меня 1 вариант под виндой убирает 0.  Аналогично и с часами и минутами № перед буквой.